# How do I send the operator "&" via an Ajax query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm currently using the following ajax function to send ajax queries.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (htmltwo) {},
    error: function (htmltwo) {}
});
```

The problem is when i send the text which include the operator "&", the items on the right of the operator is deleted. The following is my dataString.

```
var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&dateoccur=' + dateoccur + '&timeoc=' + 
timeoc + '&hitype=' + hitype + '&hid=' + hid;
```

So e.g if hid is text containing "EEEE&LLLLL", the items on the right of & will be removed when receiving it on the server side. So on the server end, will receive "EEEE". I assume ajax recognizes this because it's part of the dataString variable. How would I be able to solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried `data: { id: id, dateoccur: dateoccur, etc: etc }` to let jQuery encode the values as needed? (This would also handle values contain equals signs, etc.)

Comment: Heh, a case of making life harder on yourself by trying to do something the library already does.

Comment: Would the same problem transferred to comma (,) tho ?

Comment: jQuery will take the object and convert it into the key=value pairs.  If the value string contains anything that would cause the key value pair to be invalid, it will escape them.

Comment: Apparently not. Thanks, it works fine with comma and & operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always recommend using an object rather than a string. jQuery will then automatically encode everything properly.

```
var dataString = {
    id: id,
    dateoccur: dateoccur,
    timeoc: timeoc,
    hitype: hitype,
    hid: hid
};
```

It's also much more readable, IMHO.

But if you really want to build the string yourself, use `encodeURIComponent` as in Nisarg Shah's answer. You should do this for all parameters, unless you're sure they don't contain any special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in Javascript to encode characters such as `&` and then decode them back at the server.

```js
var hidValue = "EEEE&LLLLL";

var hidValueEncoded = encodeURIComponent(hidValue);
console.log(hidValueEncoded);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not consider this answer as I would have to change alot of code. The format data: { id: id, dateoccur: dateoccur, etc: etc } worked for me as commented above by nnnn